# Increment time session time out on running php

Tags: php

How can i increment the time of the session time out once the session has started?
I set in the php.ini file:

```
session.gc_maxlifetime = 3600
```

but i need to keep alive the session while the user has the page open.

Comment: `ini_set()`? and of what purpose is a random lifetime?

Comment: are you saying a different timeout for each user? o.O

Comment: if you set gc_maxlifetime = 0, session never ending

Comment: the session needs to remain open while the user has the web page open

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this

```
ini_set("session.gc_maxlifetime", 3600);
```

Look here for more info: https://www.php.net/ini_set

Comment: but you can use this to reset locally during runtime.

Comment: Actually the ini_set needs to be called before the session_start(), after this, it doesnt have any effect. My web page stays open after the session_start()

Answer (score 0):

If you really want a different timeout for each user, then I would do:
`ini_set(session.gc_maxlifetime, 43200); // 12 hours`
As your max range then say:

```
$customEndTime = (rand(0, 4320) * 10) + time(); // max rand is usually 32767
$_SESSION['endTime'] = $customEndTime;
```

When you go to check your session variables, just add that check in there and if the `customEndTime > time()`, then reset the users session using `session_destroy();`

You can of course increase 43200 to whatever you need. To calculate it, say: `60*60*$maxNumberOfHours`